# Is it possible to reduce the number of images in batch in convert_imageset.cpp to tackle out of memory of GPU?

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe, lmdb, deeplearning4j

I was trying to run fcn on my data in caffe. I was able to convert my image sets into `lmdb` by `convert_imageset` builtin function caffe. However, once I wanted to train the `net`, it gave me the following error:

```
Check failed: error == cudaSuccess (2 vs. 0)  out of memory
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
.....
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I went through many online resources to solve the memory failure, but most of them suggesting reducing batch size. Even, I reduced the size of images to 256x256. I could not tackle this issue yet. 
I checked the memory of GPU by this command `nvidia-smi`, and the model is `Nvidia GT 730` and the memory is `1998 MiB`. Since the batch size in `train_val.prototxt` is 1, I can not do anythin in `train_val.prototxt`. So my questions are:

1. By looking at log file in Terminal,I realized that whenever `convert_imageset` converting the data into LMDB, it is taking 1000 image in a group. Is it possible I change this number in line `143` and `151` of [`convert_imageset.cpp`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/tools/convert_imageset.cpp#L143) to a smaller (for example 2; to take two image at a time), recompile caffe, and then convert images to lmdb by using convert_imageset? Does it make sense?
2. If the answer to question 1 is yes, how can I compile caffe again,
   should I remove `build` folder and again do caffe installation from
   scratch?
3. How caffe process the LMDB data? Is it like taking a batch of those 1000 images showing while running convert_imagenet?

Your help is really appreciated.
Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK, there is no effect for the number of entries committed to lmdb at each transaction (`txn->Commit();`) on the cuda out of memory.
2. If you do want to re-compile caffe for whatever reason, simply run `make clean`. This will clear everything and let you re-compile from scratch.
3. Again, AFAIK, caffe access lmdb `batch_size` images at a time regardless of the size of the transaction size used when writing the dataset.

Are you sure `batch_size` is set to 1 for **both** TRAIN and TEST phases?

Comment: Thank you so much for your information. Yes, it is FCN semantic segmentation which the batch size is 1. Is  there any solution for my problem?

Comment: @S.EB buy a new GPU with bigger memory. :|